# The difference between the freezing point of methanol and ethanol at different concentrations

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I would like to ask a chemistry question:
The freezing point of methanol aqueous solution between 0% and 90% is lower than that of ethanol aqueous solution; but why is the freezing point of ethanol aqueous solution between 90% and 100% lower than that of methanol aqueous solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have not clarrified what percentages you are talking about. Is it by weight or volume?

Answer (score 1):

The OP's claim that "The freezing point of methanol aqueous solution between 0% and 90% is lower than that of ethanol aqueous solution" is correct as data given in [Engineering Tool Box (methanol/water)](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/methanol-water-d_987.html) and [Engineering Tool Box (ethanol/water)](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/ethanol-water-d_987.html):
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\text{% MeOH (v/v) or (w/w)} & \text{The freezing point } (\pu{^\circ C}) & \text{% EtOH (v/v)} & \text{The freezing point } (\pu{^\circ C}) \\
\hline
0  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
13 \text{ or }10 & -7 & 10 &-4 \\
24 \text{ or }20 & -18 & 20 & -9\\
35 \text{ or }30 & -26 & 30 & -15\\
46\text{ or }40 & -40 & 40 & -23\\
56\text{ or }50 & -54 & 50 & -32\\
66\text{ or }60 & -71 & 60 & -37\\
75\text{ or }70 & -82 & 70 & -48\\
83\text{ or }80 & -87 & 80 & -59\\
92\text{ or }90 & -90 & 90 & -73\\
100 & -98 & 100 & -115\\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

However the two last data points are simply the comparison of the freeing point of $100\%$ methanol and that of $100\%$ ethanol. Evidently, the freeing point of $100\%$ methanol is greater than the freeing point of $100\%$ ethanol ([See Table of Melting points of alcohols)](https://www.britannica.com/science/alcohol/Physical-properties-of-alcohols). Thus, there is not an unusual reason for this change in trend.

Comment: Methanol water has a eutectic 157 K ~0.88methanol; Ethanol water 150 K ~0.80ethanol. Just to show fp depression works both ways.

Comment: Would you give the references for these values?

Comment: I googled it; look it up. You should have been suspicious that the freezing point tables you listed showed no eutectic and researched a bit further. When a source seems to violate what one thinks he knows about chemistry it is time to look further; one or the other or perhaps both needs some refining.